# Default value for optional argument in Python:

Tags: arguments, python

I have the following method:

```
def get_data(replace_nan=False):
    if replace_nan is not False
        data[numpy.isnan(data)] = replace_nan
        return data
    else:
        return data[~numpy.isnan(data)]
```

So, if `replace_nan` is False, we return some data array but remove `NaN`s, and if it's anything else, we replace `NaN`s with the argument.

Problem is, I may want to replace `NaN` with `False`. Or anything else, for that sake. What's the most pythonic way to do so? This:

```
def get_data(**kwargs):
    if "replace_nan" in kwargs:
       ...
```

works, but is semantically ugly (because we're really just interested in one keyword argument, `replace_nan`) Any suggestions how to handle this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually people use `None` as the default value and then check for `is not None`.

If you need to allow `None`, too, use a dummy object:

```
__default = object()
def get_data(replace_nan=__default):
    if replace_nan is __default:
        ...
```

Comment: I already used `False` because `None` is a frequent replacement for missing values. But the dummy default object is neat, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

numpy evaluates False inside array to 0:

```
    >>>np.array([False,True,2,3])
    array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

So this might probably not what you want to happen.

```
    def get_data(replace_nan=False):
       if replace_nan:
          return np.where(np.isnan(data),replace_nan,data)
       else:
          return data[~numpy.isnan(data)]
```

The numpy.where function builds an array with the indexes where your entries are NaN. There it replaces the entries with replace_nan, everywhere else it keeps the entries.

From the [manual page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition.
```

Answer (score 1):

I Wanted to put this as comment below ThiefMaster's answer but no formatting in comments allowed, so ...:

If you are concerned about cluttering your namespace you can—with some tricks—`del` the variable after defining the function.

```
__default = object()
def get_data(replace_nan=__default, __default=__default):
  if replace_nan is __default:
    ...
del __default
```

Or:

```
__default = object()
def get_data(replace_nan=__default):
  if replace_nan is get_data.default_replace_nan:
    ...
get_data.default_replace_nan = __default
del __default
```

Comment: Interesting! However I always thought `__...` was meant for cluttering anyway ;-)

Comment: Traditionally __ was reserved for compiler-internal stuff in C and thus was a nono for the application builder to use.  In Python things are a little different.  Anyway:  Cluttering is a problem.  You cannot use the name `__default` for the next situation in which this pattern might be useful because you would overwrite the `__default` from the fist usage (and break the code in the process).  So cluttering should be avoided, even if `__` might make the cluttering obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to avoid the cluttering of ThiefMaster's approach is this:

```
def get_data(replace_nan=object()):
  if replace_nan is get_data.func_defaults[0]:
    ...
```

But it uses python interna which might not be as portable (pypy/stackles/next version/…).

Comment: And you even can replace the `0` in the code above with `get_data.func_code.co_varnames.index('replace_nan')` to be safe against later modifications of get_data()'s signature.  But now we are overkilling the problem I guess.